# Не корректно работают bootstrap табы

Tags: html, bootstrap

Есть код:

```html
<div class="cab-navigation">
  <h3 class="cab-navigation-title">Навигация</h3>
  <nav class="cab-nav-primary">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active">
        <div class="icon-container">
          <img src="icon/info.png" alt="Общая информация">
        </div>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-basket">Общая информация</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="icon-container">
          <img src="icon/backet.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-basket">Корзина</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="cab-tab tab-content">
  <div id="tab-basket" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="tab-basket-title">
      <h3>Корзина</h3>
      <span>Удалить все</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-basket-content">
      Some text
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="tab-bookmarks" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="tab-basket-title">
      <h3>Корзина 2</h3>
      <span>Удалить все</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-basket-content">
      Some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Я подключил 4 бутстрап. Табы работают, но некоректно. При переключение, на другой таб, первый таб также остается активным и последующий клик, по нему не возможен. 
Делал все по примеру, где все работает.
Как это исправить? нужно чтобы, при клике на следующий таб, предыдущий ставал неактивен.

Comment: `js` подключили? в код сниппет свой добавьте необходимые стили и скрипты, чтобы можно было его выполнить

Comment: @teran js подключил. Код из примера работает отлично. Хотя я все сверял.. у меня также

Comment: я не про код из примера. я про код из вопроса. Отредактируйте вопрос ([edit]) там откройте редактор сниппета (_редактировать пример кода_), и добавьте ссылки на js и css файлы вашего бутстрапа 4. Чтобы мы могли увидеть проблему наглядно.

Comment: @teran не смог сюда загрузить. сделал на https://jsfiddle.net/6bsz3s3p/ и тут все работает странно.